# Latex subsection remove dotted lines

Tags: formatting, latex, tex

Please suggest how can I remove dotted lines from the technical skills sections
[Link to error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fhCv.png)

```
\section{TECHNICAL SKILLS}
\vspace{-4mm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.6\textwidth}
\subsection{Languages}
\paragraph{Proficient:}
\textbullet{} Test \textbullet{} Test \textbullet{} Test \textbullet{} Dart \textbullet{} Test \\ 
\location{Familiar / Studying:}
\textbullet{} Test \textbullet{} Test \\
\end{minipage}
```

Find code here: https://www.overleaf.com/read/wxwpscypyhrc

Thanks,

Comment: How is your `\location` macro defined? Your code does not compile because of this. See here the error indicator: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0bpb.png

Comment: The code works.
It just gives warnings.
You can ignore them

Comment: No it does not. The red square says 4 errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several problems:

- `\location` is not defined. You must either define it or not use it. Ignoring the error messages is not an option
- In this particular documentclass `\paragraph` is not defined. You must either define it or not use it. Ignoring the error messages is not an option
- If you don't supply the required information, you must not use `\makecvtitle`. In particular an empty address causes an error message. Ignoring the error messages is not an option
- to remove the dotted lines in the subsections you can use `\renewcommand*{\subsectionrule}{}`
- the `\vspace*{-12mm}` in the preamble does nothing useful

---

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}        
% possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')
% modern themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{black}                                
% color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{import}
\vspace*{-12mm}

\name{Test}{Test}
\address{}{}{}

\newcommand*{\customcventry}[7][.25em]{
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l} 
    {\bfseries #4}
  \end{tabular}
  \hfill% move it to the right
  \begin{tabular}{l@{}}
     {\bfseries #5}
  \end{tabular} \\
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l} 
    {\itshape #3}
  \end{tabular}
  \hfill% move it to the right
  \begin{tabular}{l@{}}
     {\itshape #2}
  \end{tabular}
  \ifx&#7&%
  \else{\\%
    \begin{minipage}{\maincolumnwidth}%
      \small#7%
    \end{minipage}}\fi%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}

\newcommand*{\customcvproject}[4][.25em]{
%   \vfill\noindent
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l} 
    {\bfseries #2}
  \end{tabular}
  \hfill% move it to the right
  \begin{tabular}{l@{}}
     {\itshape #3}
  \end{tabular}
  \ifx&#4&%
  \else{\\%
    \begin{minipage}{\maincolumnwidth}%
      \small#4%
    \end{minipage}}\fi%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{12pt}

\newcommand{\location}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\paragraph}[1]{#1}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionrule}{}
\address{12 somestreet}{3456 somecity}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\vspace*{-11mm}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ c c c c }
 \faEnvelopeO\enspace \href{mailto:test@gmail.com}{\underline{test@gmail.com}} & \faGithub\enspace \href{https://github.com/}{\underline{test-name}} & \faMobile\enspace 12345678900 & \faLinkedinSquare\enspace \href{https://www.linkedin.com/}{\underline{test-test}} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\section{EDUCATION}
{\customcventry{1 Jan 1011}{Position}{University}{10 CGPA}{}{}}

{\customcventry{1 Jan 1011}{Position}{University}{10 CGPA}{}{}}

\section{PROJECTS}

{\customcvproject{Test name}{1 Jan 1011}
  {\begin{itemize}
    \item Test
    \item Reverse engineered obfuscated Java using a decompiler and reflection
  \end{itemize}
  }
}

{\customcvproject{Test name}{1 Jan 1011}
  {\begin{itemize}
    \item Test
    \item Reverse engineered obfuscated Java using a decompiler and reflection
  \end{itemize}
  }

{\customcvproject{Test name}{1 Jan 1011}
  {\begin{itemize}
    \item Test
    \item Reverse engineered obfuscated Java using a decompiler and reflection
  \end{itemize}
  }
}

\section{EXPERIENCE}

{\customcventry{Jan 1011}{Position}{Company}{US}{}
{\begin{itemize}
  \item Designed and built the first version of infrastructure code base which  teams’ monthly expenses on AWS servers by 100 thousand dollars.
\end{itemize}
}
}

{\customcventry{Jan 1011}{Position}{Company}{US}{}
{\begin{itemize}
  \item Designed and built the first version of infrastructure code base which  teams’ monthly expenses on AWS servers by 100 thousand dollars.
\end{itemize}
}
}

{\customcventry{Jan 1011}{Position}{Company}{US}{}
{\begin{itemize}
  \item Designed and built the first version of infrastructure code base which  teams’ monthly expenses on AWS servers by 100 thousand dollars.
\end{itemize}
}
}

{\customcventry{Jan 1011}{Position}{Company}{US}{}
{\begin{itemize}
  \item Designed and built the first version of infrastructure code base which  teams’ monthly expenses on AWS servers by 100 thousand dollars.
\end{itemize}
}
}

\section{TECHNICAL SKILLS}
\vspace{-4mm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.6\textwidth}
\subsection{Languages}
\paragraph{Proficient:}
\textbullet{} Test \textbullet{} Test \textbullet{} Test \textbullet{} Dart \textbullet{} Test \\ 
\location{Familiar / Studying:}
\textbullet{} Test \textbullet{} Test \\
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
\subsection{Spoken \& Written}
\location{Fluent:} \textbullet{} Test \textbullet{} Test \textbullet{} Test \\
\location{Learning:} \textbullet{} Test \\
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.6\textwidth}
\subsection{Frameworks}
\textbullet{} Test \textbullet{} Test \textbullet{} Test \textbullet{} Test \\
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
\subsection{Software / Version Control}
\textbullet{} Test \\
\end{minipage}

\vspace{-3mm}

\section{AWARDS AND ACHIEVEMENTS}
\begin{minipage}{\maincolumnwidth}%
    \small{
        \begin{itemize}
          \item Test
          \item Test
          \item Test
          \item Test
          \item Test
          \item Test
          \item Test
        \end{itemize}}%
\end{minipage}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works!
Thanks for the detailed explaination.